# How to install a github service hook that is able to prevent a push

Tags: git, github

After reading through several SOF questions as well as github doc's the nearest information I can find on installing git hooks on github is a list of supported services, here:  https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#services

However that page does not describe either

- Does the service permit acceptance/rejection of git push'es
- An example of how  to implement a push service for a repository on github.com

Clarification of the first bullet item and example code/script for the second would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE** It is seeming that github does not support server side git hooks.  Any workarounds for this limitation would be appreciated.  We are seeking to prevent following on master branch:

- rebase
- commit
- push

Why? We are intending to only ever update Master directly from the original source repo (ours is a fork) *directly on Github.com* and *never* on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent a push with a service. GitHub services are things that receive a notification that a repo changed, and can take an independent action as a result.

Comment: That was kinda my impression. Any suggestions as to addressing my original intent - prevent pushes to master branch?

Comment: @javadba: Under what conditions are you trying to prevent pushes?

Comment: All conditions. No changes are ever to be made to master at any time via the command line. This repo is a fork of a github repo from which we will do periodic sync'ing (from the source to our fork) directly on the github gui and nowhere else. All of our own work will be in feature branches.

Comment: @javadba: If it's an organization repo, you can give read-only access to certain repo teams: https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository

Comment: Thanks but that is not the intent. All members will have write access but nooone should be able to update master. That does not correspond to the R/O capability at the repo level -instead it is a branch-level permission.

Comment: @javadba: You can't do branch-level permissions on repos hosted on GitHub.

Comment: I guess this question is evolving towards: How do organizations manage large projects that share a single repo - which is itself a clone of an apache project? Given that github does not support per-branch permissions, a robust workflow is not immediately apparent.

Comment: @javadba: I think typically they would communicate policies to developers, i.e., tell them not to push to master (and then yell at them if they do—almost everything in Git can be undone anyway).

Comment: Yes, I was the one doing the yelling ;)  The team lead and I are trying to find a means to provide some automated enforcement.

Comment: Although I am pretty much where I started, this answer at least seems to confirm my suspicion that there is no mechanism to provide the branch permissions we seek . At this point I will award.